# Move an UI item

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with a UI line.

Here is my code :

```
Vector3 pointA = a.transform.position, pointB = b.transform.position;
Vector3 dif = pointB - pointA;
RectTransform imageRectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
imageRectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(dif.magnitude, imageRectTransform.sizeDelta.y);
imageRectTransform.pivot = new Vector2(0, 0.05f);
imageRectTransform.position = pointA;
float angle = Mathf.Atan2(dif.y, dif.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
imageRectTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle);
```

Result of this code:

[image: Current result]

What I want:

[image: Wanted result]

I tried with `imageRectTransform.Translate(Vector3.right * 1000)`

**NOTES** : This `Vector3.right` value is just a test.
            The two game objects are moving.